# SQL Server Security: Allow table update from application only

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a database on which all application users are having access to, using Windows Authentication. There is one  table which I want to be updateable only through the Application user interface and not by directly logging into SQL Server Management Studio.

I have researched about SQL Server security but all it says is, if a user is having access to a database object then it is allowed through any interface or management studio. I wonder if there would be some solution to this weird scenario.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Trigger` on your table for preventing  updating from SSMS.

and differ the application name via using system function:

```
 APP_NAME()
```

**Example:**

```
--Create Test table
Create table test (id int , name varchar (20))
go
--insert dummy data
insert into Test values (1, 'aaaa'), (2,'bbbb')
go

-- create our trigger for preventing updating via SSMS
CREATE TRIGGER trgPreventUpdateTestTableViaSSMS
ON test
FOR UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
    IF APP_NAME() = 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query' 
    begin
        RAISERROR('Cannot update test table via using SSMS',16,1) 
        rollback
        end
END
GO

-- try update
update Test set name = 'cccc' where id = 2
```

**The Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the permissions for the table to SELECT only. Then, you can create a stored procedure for updating of this table. You will grant the execute permissions to the users who are allowed updating of this table.

To make it run from the application only you may add a parameter (like a @authentication_key) that is passed from the application (hard-coded into the application). In the SP you would validate the key if it matches some pre-defined value.

To make the SP code unreadable you will create the SP with the `WITH ENCRYPTION` option. When you do this you will need to save the souarce of your SP elsewhere, as you will not be able to retrieve the source from SQL Server